# Split string into new record every time a certain condition is met

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

I use a string file in SQL to create a report in crystal reports. The problem is that crystal reports is not interpreting the page breaks.  Is there a split function that can search through a string and every time Owner no. occurs, split the string into a new record? The string are large,(above 1000 characters). 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to put *SQL 2008* in the title as this is what the tags are for.

Comment: Duplicate?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql.

Comment: Not answering the SQL question but if it's being displayed as a record in a column in crystal report, did you try "Can grow" option in crystal report to wrap into multiple lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place in Details section:

```
//{@block 0}
Local Stringvar CRLF := Chr(10)+Chr(13);

If Instr({table.field}, CRLF) Then
  Split({table.field}, CRLF)[1]
Else
  {table.field}
```

insert this formula its own Details section; mark section 'suppress when blank' and 'new page before':

```
//{@block 1}
Local Stringvar CRLF := Chr(10)+Chr(13);

If Instr({table.field}, CRLF) Then
  Split({table.field}, CRLF)[2]
```